# 'sphinx-autodoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I am fairly new to building documentation with sphinx. I was able to use sphinx-quickstart on Anaconda prompt and it created all the folders properly. I am able to generate .rst files with sphinx-apidoc too. However, when I try to use the sphinx-autodoc command I get the following error:

```
'sphinx-autodoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have enabled this extension on the conf.py file, which looks like this:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../fed3live'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'fed3live'
copyright = '####'
author = '###'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '0.0.3'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon']

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'alabaster'

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

I have checked in the Lib/site-packages/sphinx/ext folder of my environment and I do see an autodoc and a napoleon folder. Does anyone know why it's not recognizing this command?

Thanks

Comment: There is no command called `sphinx-autodoc`. The command that generates HTML output is `sphinx-build`.